# HTML CSS How to stop a table to put the content after it on a new line?

Tags: html, css, line

I have a table followed by an anchor tag. I want the anchor tag not to move to next line after the table.

What are the options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want the anchor to be right to the table?

Use the CSS-argument "float".

```
<table style="float:left"></table>
<tag></tag>
```

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Apply the CSS rule `float: left` to the table.